# Broadcast server and client on the same script?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have the following scripts:

```
import socket
import sys
import traceback
msg = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
dest = ('<broadcast>',10100)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto(msg, dest)
print "Sent."
while 1:
    (buf,address)=s.recvfrom(10100)
    if not len(buf):
        break
    print "Received from %s: %s" %(address, buf)
```

And then:

```
import socket
import traceback
import os
host = ''
port = 10100
sx = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sx.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sx.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
sx.bind((host,port))
while 1:
    try:
        message, address = sx.recvfrom(10104)
        print "Got data from", address
        sx.sendto("ola",address)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

I'm having some trouble having both of them on the same script.
I just wanted to learn more about sockets, etc, this is nothing in particular.
My idea was to have just one script in each machine (Raspberry Pi), and whenever they're on the same network, one will know about the presence of the other.
Hope I had explained right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.
I've found these two links. 
The first one is really great, simple and is working like needed. May help someone else:
http://www.cs.bilgi.edu.tr/~mgencer/Ders%20Malzemeleri/IThingTaggedFile/p2p.py

https://github.com/zetaron/python-udp-p2p

Answer (score 0):

You can send and receive on the same socket, you don't need the second one. Use something like [`select`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) with a timeout to wait for others to contact you, broadcast on the timeout expiring to let others know about yourself (you might want to keep something like time left to next broadcast, so you don't lose broadcasting schedule on receipt of a datagram).

Comment: Can you point me some website or pdf with samples?
I'm trying to develop myself, but sometimes it doesn't send the message to other peers. Thank you.